# adding a privacy policy activity to a kiosk android app

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

I`m new to android and i am expected to add a privacy policy page on launch inside this app. The app is suppose to be put in a kiosk outside some retailers, so the tablet is pretty much locked on the app. whenever the user presses the home button on the tablet it goes to our app instead of the android home. All this works fine with the MainActivity as the entry point.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

What needs to be done is to add a privacy policy activity as the entry point but, keep the main activity as the home screen. could someone point me out as to what the manifest would look like?

Comment: could you explain a little bit about kiosk?

Comment: as i mentioned above the user is not allowed to go back to to the android home hence the `<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />`. This means that whenever the user taps the home button, the tablet goes to the app more specifically the mainActivity, instead of the android home. So in the settings the home is the app.